# 2012 Mitsubishi Galant SE

Tags: mitsubishi, air-intake, galant

So I have a 2012 Mitsubishi Galant 2.4l and I'm looking for a cold air intake system but there isn't one for my car. I've been looking at a lot of websites but there's nothing. I searched and I found that the Mitsubishi Eclipse 2006 has the same engine and the same air intake so I'm trying to see if that one fits with my car because it looks exactly the same as the 2012 Mitsubishi Galant. I just want to know if I can use one from the Mitusbishi Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with such things unless you are going to do ECU tuning to match.

A number of aftermarket CAI units are nothing but *snake oil* to make an engine run lean, increasing power at the expense of unwanted heat and higher NOx emissions.

The factory airbox is often very well designed, and not a conspiracy to rob power - despite shadetree claims otherwise.  I admit that the huge *suck* noise is often pretty cool.  Even better if the ECU is remapped to actually utilize the small flow gains properly.

Answer (score 2):

Both the Galant and the Eclipse had the same 2 engines available for each other. The air intakes should be interchangeable from 2006 to 2012, as long as it's for the same engine you have (the 2.4L 4 cylinder, not the 3.8L V6).